# CSS 3D isometric simple rotation transform

Tags: css, transform, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to do a small CSS animation with a `door` like folding animation. I use a SVG as the base, gave it an isometric transform and now I would like the orange square to fold as if it was a 3D space.

I tried to play with perspective, skewing, transform 3D but failed.

```css
#svgbox {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
  left: 200px;
}
#rect5 {
  animation: rect5anim 3s ease forwards;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  perspective: 1500px;
  /*transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
}
@keyframes rect5anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="svgbox">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient x1="123.587715%" y1="49.9380835%" x2="24.1186732%" y2="49.9380835%" id="linearGradient-1" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#F6851F" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#F59427" offset="28.32%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#F5BB42" offset="100%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="126.190394%" y1="50.060688%" x2="22.2418719%" y2="50.060688%" id="linearGradient-2" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#F6851F" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#F5BB42" offset="100%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="122.778325%" y1="50.0081081%" x2="24.5036946%" y2="50.0081081%" id="linearGradient-3" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#8CC151" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#98C54C" offset="14.59%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#D7DF23" offset="99%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="-27.65086%" y1="50.0081081%" x2="72.4520885%" y2="50.0081081%" id="linearGradient-4" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#8CC151" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#D7DF23" offset="99%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <rect id="rect1" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" />
      <rect id="rect2" x="201" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" />
      <rect id="rect3" x="401" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" />
      <rect id="rect4" x="601" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" />
      <rect id="rect5" x="801" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" />

      <rect id="rect6" y="201" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-3)" />
      <rect id="rect7" y="401" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-4)" />
      <rect id="rect8" y="601" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-4)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using the `perspective` property and not applying perspective to the transform (`transform: perspective(x)`). The `perspective` property does not affect the rendering of an element. It only creates a 3D space that will be used by its children. You can find more information about this in [this CSS Tricks Article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/).

Another thing that might be worth noting is that percentage values for `transform-origin` don't seem to work well in Firefox. It requires px based values and that too it should be in reference to the SVG's (0,0). So, for `#rect5`, setting `transform-origin: 801px 100px` produces the expected output in FF. [This CSS Tricks Article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/) has detailed information about this particular problem.

Below is a snippet which uses transform with a perspective in-order to produce the needed effect.

```css
#svgbox {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
  left: 200px;
}
#rect5 {
  animation: rect5anim 3s ease forwards;
  transform-origin: 801px 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
@keyframes rect5anim {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="svgbox">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient x1="123.587715%" y1="49.9380835%" x2="24.1186732%" y2="49.9380835%" id="linearGradient-1" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#F6851F" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#F59427" offset="28.32%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#F5BB42" offset="100%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="126.190394%" y1="50.060688%" x2="22.2418719%" y2="50.060688%" id="linearGradient-2" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#F6851F" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#F5BB42" offset="100%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="122.778325%" y1="50.0081081%" x2="24.5036946%" y2="50.0081081%" id="linearGradient-3" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#8CC151" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#98C54C" offset="14.59%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#D7DF23" offset="99%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="-27.65086%" y1="50.0081081%" x2="72.4520885%" y2="50.0081081%" id="linearGradient-4" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop stop-color="#8CC151" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#D7DF23" offset="99%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <rect id="rect1" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" />
      <rect id="rect2" x="201" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" />
      <rect id="rect3" x="401" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" />
      <rect id="rect4" x="601" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" />
      <rect id="rect5" x="801" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" />

      <rect id="rect6" y="201" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-3)" />
      <rect id="rect7" y="401" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-4)" />
      <rect id="rect8" y="601" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#linearGradient-4)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```